# Keeping your main form class short best practice

Tags: c#

I have a main form at present it has a tab control and 3 data grids (DevExpress xtragrid's). Along with the normal buttons combo boxes... I would say 2/3 rds of the methods in the main form are related to customizing the grids or their relevant event handlers to handle data input. This is making the main forms code become larger and larger.

What is an ok sort of code length for a main form?

How should I move around the code if necesary? I am currently thinking about creating a user control for each grid and dumping it's methods in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I build a fair number of apps at my shop and try to avoid, as a general rule, to clog up main forms with a bunch of control-specific code.  Rather, I'll encapsulate behaviors and state setup into some commonly reusable user controls and stick that stuff in the user controls' files instead.

I don't have a magic number I shoot for in the main form, instead I'll use the 'Why would I put this here?' test.  If I can't come up with a good reason as to why I'm thinking of putting the code in the main form, I'll avoid it. Otherwise, as you've mentioned, the main form starts growing and it becomes a real pain to manage everything.

I like to put my glue code (event handler stuff, etc.) separate from the main form itself.

At a minimum, I'll utilize some regions to separate the code out into logically grouped chunks.  Granted, many folks hate the #region/#endregion constructs, but I've got the keystrokes pretty much all memorized so it isn't an issue for me.  I like to use them simply because it organizes things nicely and collapses down well in VS.

In a nutshell, I don't put anything in the main form unless I convince myself it belongs there.  There are a bunch of good patterns out there that, when employed, help to avoid the big heaping pile that otherwise tends to develop.  I looked back at one file I had early on in my career and the darn thing was 10K lines long... absolutely ridiculous!

Anyway, that is my two cents.

Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

As with any class, having more than about 150 lines is a sign that something has gone horribly wrong. The same OO principles apply to classes relating to UI as everywhere else in your application.

The class should have a single responsibility.

Comment: And arbitrarily deciding that 150 lines is a limit, and you need to split into separate classes is a sign that your code is likely overcomplicated by having WAY more classes than are really necessary ;)  (just playing devil's advocate, but as a rule, any arbitrary rules = bad)

Comment: I don't think 150 lines is an arbitrary limit - however, I'd be concerned if a class was longer than that (a code smell). I don't think having large classes that violate SRP makes for a less complicated system

Answer (score 0):

A number is hard to come up with.  In general, I agree with the previous two posters, it's all about responsibilities.

Ask yourself, what does the code to customize behavior for grid 1 have to do with grid 2?

What is the responsibility of the main form?  Recently I have been subscribing to MVP design patterns (MVC is fine as well).  In this pattern, you main form is the presenter, or ui layer.  It's responsibility should be to present data and accept user input.

Without seeing your code, I can only guesstimate as to what is the best course of action.  But I agree with your feelings that each grid and it's customization code should live in a different control.  Perhaps the responsibility of the main form should be to merely pass the data to the correct control and pass requests from the control back to the controller/presenter.  It is the responsibility of each control to understand the data passed to it, and display it accordingly.

Attached is an example MVP implementation.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/PassiveView01262008091652AM/PassiveView.aspx